# How to add custom options for plugin into the add post screen - like yoast seo

Tags: plugin-development, plugin-wp-seo-yoast

On Yoast seo, when you create a new page it gives you the ability to alter titles, etc. This is added by the yoast module.
I am writing a plugin, that can have other things attaching to a post. How can I modify the admin panel to add these new option?
Thanks
John

Comment: Simply take a look at the yoast plugin and search for `add_meta_box()`...

Answer (score 2):

what you are looking for is call in the WordPress world  a MetaBox and just like Yoast SEO you need to use [**add_meta_box()**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function to add your own.

there is a great tutorial and class you can use in your plugin at [deluxeblogtips.com](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/p/meta-box-script-for-wordpress.html)
 I would suggest you use that for a starting point.